# Cannot create Button in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What I found in most of the tutorial on the internet is:

```
@Composable
fun addButton() {
   Button(text = "I'm a Compose Button")
}
```

But android studio give me an error: type mismatch Required: () -> Unit, Found: String.
I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: "What I found in most of the tutorial on the internet" -- check the dates on those tutorials. Jetpack Compose is still in a developer preview right now, and that means that the API changes very quickly.

Answer (score 9):

According to the docs, To create a [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/material/package-summary#Button(kotlin.Function0,%20androidx.ui.core.Modifier,%20kotlin.Boolean,%20androidx.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.ui.graphics.Shape,%20androidx.ui.foundation.Border,%20androidx.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.ui.graphics.Color,%20androidx.ui.layout.InnerPadding,%20kotlin.Function1)) you have to specify the text inside the [RowScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/layout/RowScope.html):

```kotlin
Button(onClick = {/* To execute when button is clicked */}) {
    Text("I'm a Compose Button")
}
```

The text is then set by [Text()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/foundation/package-summary#text) function defined in androidx.ui.foundation package.

You can find more about them in the material-ui docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/material/package-summary

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can add Button in Jetpack compose.

```java
Button(onClick = {/*Handle click action */}, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
    Text(
        text = "Jetpack Compose Button"
    )
}
```

References:

[1] https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#button

Answer (score 0):

Use blow code

```
Button(onClick {/* your onClick listener */}){
   Text("I'm a Compose Button")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it does not seems good but u have to do it like this

```
                Button(onClick = {handle Click Action }) 
                     {
                    Text(text = "Your Button Text")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

those who are new in compose can use button simple button like this

```
    @Composable
fun MyButton() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = Dp(10f)),
            enabled = true,
            border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, brush = SolidColor(Color.Blue))

        ) {
            Text(text = "I am a compose button", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the syntax,

you the this code:

```
    Button(onClick = {/*Handle click action */} ){
    Text(
        text = "Write the button text here"
    )
}
```

if you want to use modifiers then refer to this,

```
    Button(onClick = {/*Handle click action */}, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
    Text(
        text = "Write the button text here"
    )
}
```